# when i run my application on android emulator it crashed though there is no error in my code.it shows the following error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

***Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.EditText.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference at com.example.temperaturecricket.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25).***

> **this is where it highlights my error.**

```
     '''
**`etChirps.findViewById(R.id.etChirps);`**
'''
```

this is my whole code

`package com.example.temperaturecricket;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etChirps;
    Button btnCalculate;
    TextView tvResults;
    DecimalFormat formatter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        etChirps = findViewById(R.id.etChirps);

        btnCalculate.findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);
        tvResults.findViewById(R.id.tvResults);

        tvResults.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            formatter=new DecimalFormat("#0.0");
        btnCalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if(etChirps.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please Enter All fields ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    int chirps=Integer.parseInt(etChirps.getText().toString().trim());
                    double temp=(chirps/3.0)+4;
                    String result="The Approx Temperature outside is : "+formatter.format(temp)+" Degree Celsius";
                    tvResults.setText(result);
                    tvResults.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }
        });
    }


}'
```

Comment: Post the relevant part of the code, EG the method where `etChirps.findViewById(R.id.etChirps)` is

Answer (score 1):

The problem is:

```
 etChirps.findViewById(R.id.etChirps);
```

If you want to find your View with its id, use: `view = findViewByID(R.id.viewId);` instead of `view.findViewById(R.id.viewId);`

In your case you should use:

```
 etChirps = findViewById(R.id.etChirps);
 btnCalculate = findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);
 tvResults = findViewById(R.id.tvResults);
```

Comment: i have tried this but still problem exists i have posted my whole code above. Can you please read it thoroughly.thx

Comment: TextView (tvResults) and Button (btnCalculate) also have  same problem